# Proving that $\pi$ can be computed by colliding blocks

Tags: mathematical-physics, pi

I recently watched 3Blue1Brown's YouTube video ["The most unexpected answer to a counting puzzle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs), and the video suggested (at time 2:56) that an inefficient and elegant way to express $\pi$ is:

> 1. Implement a physics engine, where:
>
>    - Create 2 blocks, and a wall on the left side, while the right side leads towards infinity
>    - The second block is bigger, starts out at the right of the smaller one(which has a mass of 1).
>    - Set the number of digits you want to compute to a variable N
>    - Set the mass of the heavier block to 100 to the power of N-1
> 2. Give the second block some initial push. (Doesn't really matter speed)
> 3. The rules are:
>
>    - All collisions are elastic (no energy is lost, thus the momentum is completely preserved and transferred)
>    - There are no friction to affect the sliding of the blocks
>
> Thus:
>
> - $\pi$ with $N$ digits is equivalent to the number of collisions of both blocks and the wall.

Is there any more ways to prove the fact while being both easy-to-understand and able to be graphed out, apart from 3Blue1Brown's ways to prove it?

Comment: You could put a link to the video? I would guess this iterative effect might be representable as a continued fraction of some kind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Generalized_continued_fraction

Comment: I've added the relevant YouTube link.

Comment: Have you watched 3B1B's videos showing why it works, in particular how the setup is analogous to a straight line drawn through slices of a circle? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsYwFizhncE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brU5yLm9DZM

Comment: Maybe if you edit in a summary of 3blue1brown's proof, you can point to an aspect of it you'd want other proofs to avoid, e.g. a step that's less intuitive than you'd like.